# How do you use XMLHttpRequest with POST method?

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, http-post, php-5.6

I have a central PHP script I use for handling many requests from my page, using XMLHttpRequest() calls from JavaScript, using the GET method. My server PHP is currently 5.6, and yes, I'm avoiding synchronous calls.

It all works well, however there are cases where I'd prefer NOT to have the request remain in browser history, or even be displayed in the URL. So based on the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) on this call, I thought I could simply switch to the POST method, keeping my existing requests (such as "http://myscript.php?cmd=dothis&data=somedata"). then all I'd have to do is add some code to my PHP script, so I could gather the passed data either way...

```
if  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    if(isset($_GET['cmd'])) $cmd = $_GET['cmd'];
    if(isset($_GET['data'])) $data =  $_GET['data'];  
    }

if  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['cmd'])) $cmd = $_POST['cmd'];
    if(isset($_POST['data'])) $data =  $_POST['data'];  
    }
```

Well obviously i was dead wrong. What I found was...

1. Neither of the variables shown in this example are seen by the script within the $_POST array, when I switch to the POST method.
2. Switching from the $_POST array to the $_REQUEST array works fine (eg: "if(isset($_REQUEST['cmd'])) $cmd = $_REQUEST['cmd']);" ), BUT....
3. Just the act of issuing my XMLHttpRequest() calls with the POST method, results in errors like this in my log:

> PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

So obviously This is a dead end. Doing my best to research what is going on here, in the [PHP manual reference to POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) I read this right on top...

> $_POST $HTTP_POST_VARS [deprecated]

So if I'm understanding this right, the reason I can only obtain the POST variables using the $_REQUEST array is because my requests are still formatted as if I were still using GET, which (apparently?) is a deprecated method. Therefore, "coaxing" it to work is just moving the problem to the future.

Incidentally, I can see by calling the phpinfo.php on my server that despite the ERROR I see in my logs, "always_populate_raw_post_data" is indeed already set to "-1". So all the "solutions" I've found recommending I "JUST" make this setting in my PHP.INI file do not help.

And even if it DID "hide" the error, doing so  seems irrelevant to me. Am I wrong in saying that even if I simply gather my passed PHP vars from the $_REQUEST array when using the POST method, AND figure out a way to suppressing the "deprecated" warnings in my LOG, the whole scheme would still fall apart (and make my POST requests fail), the day I finally migrate to PHP 7.x.?

I apologize for asking here, but I have really tried to search every reference I could find for both doing XMLHttpRequests using POST method, AND the deprecated error messages I get in my logs. There is so much obsolete info out there, I can't find any clear discussion on how to PROPERLY alter or re-format my XMLHttpRequests so that I can use the POST method. In fact, I can't even positively determine whether doing so will be possible beyond PHP.5.6. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Using POST doesn't affect parameters being carried by as QUERY_STRING still. Showcasing some browser network request might be more useful than alluding to some unused  $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA log entry.

Comment: Thanks @mario. Quentin's answer below made this all very clear. In all honesty, there were elements of what was happening that made me unsure how to better explain it, other than to offer the minimum things needed to replicate the problem. I'm learning slowly that formulating a good question is often just as hard, if not harder, than offering a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP made a mistake of naming `$_GET` and `$_POST` after the default place that a web browser will put data in an HTML form where the `method` attribute is set to GET or POST.

`$_GET` gets data from the query string, even if the request method was POST.

The request body is determined by the argument you pass to `send`. Data you put in the query string remains in the query string.

```
const url = 'http://myscript.php'
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("cmd", "dothis");
form_data.append("data", "somedata");
cost xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST", url);
xhr.addEventListener('load', function () { console.log(this.response); });
xhr.send(form_data);
```

Comment: Very helpful!! Please help me be clear. In my example i was not creating a form object. I simply passed my vars in the URL (what you're calling the query string, right?). Well still using my example, method, Yes, I did see that the data shows up in the $_GET array, even when i specify POST, But I still got the "deprecated" error I described, my biggest concern. So when I switched to your example, using a FormDat obj, THEN I only saw the data in the $_POST array. And more important, NO deprecation errors! So, (1) a form obj is the right way to do POST (2) This will till work in PHP 7.. Right?

Comment: Passing a FormData object will cause XHR to construct a standard multipart mime request body and matching Content-Type header. You could also use form/url-encoded data, but there isn't as nice an API for that. Multipart mime has been a standard way to send data over HTTP since HTML 3.2 and isn't going away any time soon.

Comment: By the way, and not for my own increase in reputation at all, but consider upvoting my question, for the benefit of many seekers who have been battling this issue for years! I searched stackoverflow, stackexchange, and many lesser known online forums before posting here. Not only did I find few relevent posts beyond the obvious PHP.INI setting, but this is the first time I've seen a clear example of an approach that  is easy, works perfectly, and is accompanied by explanations that explain the problem.The MDM reference link to XMLHttpRequest I cited offers no clue to what you explained!